# Pin Footer/View to bottom of screen programmatically with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView`, but I would like an **ever present `UIView` at the bottom of the `TableViewController` screen**.

I want to use AutoLayout programmatically to pin this view to the bottom and sides of the screen, because it needs to work with multiple screen sizes.

*I ran into problems trying to add a footer view to the `UITableView` because I wasn't able to pin it to the bottom of the screen (edge cases where there is only 1 item in the `UITableView` would render the footer in the middle of the screen.*

Is there any way to do that well?

I've started with this, but I'm stuck trying to figure out what to put for the frame since the frame will change based on screen size:

```
let bottomView = UIView()
bottomView.backgroundColor = .black
view.addSubview(bottomView)
```

Comment: Use `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` (which means you will have to add your own `UITableView`), then add your own subview at the bottom of the view controller. `UITableViewController` prevents you from doing things like this with its view hierarchy.

Comment: @keithbhunter I was hoping changing to `UIViewController` wasn't the only way, but you're saying UITableViewController` 100% doesn't allow this then huh?

Comment: `UITableViewController` doesn't allow adding subviews. I'm not sure how it does it, but anything you add won't show up. Unless you are using the default edit button functionality, you won't be missing anything by switching to `UIViewController`, and will be gaining more precise control of your table view, should you need it in the future.